# Is there an easy way to get from Twilio API the date of the first call without iterating the result?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

With the Twilio API or any of it's APIs.

Is there a way to get the data sorted by date in ascending order?

I need to get for a number of sub accounts the date the first call was made with the caller ids in the account.

I'm trying to find a way without having to go through all the results in Calls resource.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I could not find any reference in the Twilio's API docs about changing the order to ascending.

But..., you can get the calls for a specific date with a GET request something like this:

```
$ curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[SUBACCOUNT_SID]/Calls.json \
    -d "Status=completed" \
    -d "StartTime=2009-07-06" \
    -u '[MASTER_ACCOUNT_SID]:your_auth_token'
```

***Docs:***
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/call?code-sample=code-retrieve-call-by-start-date&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json

---

The question is, `how do you know the date?` You can get the date when the subaccount was created from the `USAGE RECORDS` resource.

```
$ curl -G https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/[SUBACCOUNT_SID]/Usage/Records.json \
    -u '[MASTER_ACCOUNT_SID]:your_auth_token'
```

***Docs:***
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/usage-records?code-sample=code-get-all-records&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json

This GET request will return among other things, the date when the subaccount was created. You can then use it for the other request. You might have to iterate to next days if the first call was not made exactly the day when the subaccount was created.

For both API requests you can use `?PageSize=1000` in the query string to increase the number of records returned per page.